# SearchView is not hiding from Toolbar in different Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-menu

I have implemented `SearchView` inside one of a `Fragment` of `Tablayout`. It is working fine(show/hide) when switching between tablayout fragments.

My issue is that I have a `HomeActivity` in which I have implemented `NavigationDrawer` in one of a `Fragment` I have added `TabLayout` and in one of `TabLayout Fragment` I have added `SearchView`. Issue occurs when I am switching from `Fragment` which has a `SearchView` to `Fragment` from NavDrawer. 
Searchview remains up there in other fragments too and when I switch back to that fragment in which I have added searchView then that fragment add one more searchview over `Toolbar`.

Here's my code from Fragment which as a `SearchView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        ....
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        LogUtils.LOGI("menu added", "menu");
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        //SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        //SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        //searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                LogUtils.LOGI("Search filter", query);
                final ArrayList<EventModel> filteredModelList = filter(allEventseventsArrayList, query);
                allEventsListAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
                eventbriteListRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                return true;
            }
        });


        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LogUtils.LOGI("Search", "Search Expands");
                titleIconImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                LogUtils.LOGI("Search", "Search Collapse");
                titleIconImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return false;
            }
        });

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // Return true to allow the action view to expand
                        titleIconImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        LogUtils.LOGI("Menu", "Menu Expands");
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // When the action view is collapsed, reset the query
                        LogUtils.LOGI("Menu", "Menu Collapse");
                        titleIconImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // Return true to allow the action view to collapse
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

`Fragment` code in which I don't want `SearchView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        ....
}
```

I haven't added any code related to menu in activity.

First run Image with searchView
[image]

Image after switching to different fragment from navMenu
[image]

Image again switching to fragment which has menu
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hacky but I solved it by setting setHasOptionsMenu to true and clearing the Menu in onCreateOptionsMenu via

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
   menu.clear()
}
```